# Use an Int64 in C# Tuple

Tags: c#, generics, tuples

I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm getting a compiler error when using the `.Create()` method of the new `Tuple` class.

```
Dictionary<long, Tuple<long, long>> test = new Dictionary<long, Tuple<long, long>>();
test.Add(1, Tuple.Create(1, 2)); // <-- compiler error
```

The error is that `Tuple.Create` has invalid arguments, as it is expecting longs, and the numbers I've put in are being considered as integers.

In this case yes they are within the range of int, but they may may sometimes have a value too big for an int.

I could cast `(long)1` to get the code to compile, but this doesn't seem right - what am I missing?

Comment: Because `.Create` makes a `Tuple<int, int>`, since it has to *guess*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is equivalent:

```
Tuple<long, long> yourTuple = Tuple.Create(1, 1);
```

But, because `1` can be either `int` or `long`, so by default, compiler will return `Tuple<int, int>` when calling:

```
 Tuple.Create(1, 1)
```

That is why you get compiler error. Therefore, you need to make casting explicitly by using generic version:

```
Tuple.Create<long, long>(1, 1);
```

Comment: Ah, yeah this is what I was trying to do, but was making the mistake of putting Tuple<long, long>.Create (!)

Comment: Accepted this answer as the use of generic version is in line with the rest of my code. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`L` suffix](http://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix) to specify that you want your numbers to be of type `long`:

```
test.Add(1, Tuple.Create(1L, 2L));
```

Without the suffix, .NET assumes these numbers to be `int`s and thus creates a `Tuple<int, int>` instance instead of the desired `Tuple<long, long>`.

Comment: I like it, since it’s least verbose, but still declarative.

Comment: Removed the unnecessary suffix on the key, it will auto convert to `long` already.